# Whats the best way to loop a delete query

Tags: c#, sql

I've been trying to delete several rows one by one depending on an amount of restrictions, im trying to delete only the latest entries however, the solution i have came up with keep crashing VSHOST, is there a better way to achieve the same result?

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("A apagar dados...");
    bool check = true;
    do
    {
        string connectionString;
        var path = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\connstring.txt";
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            connectionString = sr.ReadLine();
        }

        var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        string queryString = string.Empty;
        using (SqlConnection deleteconnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            deleteconnection.Open();
            connection.Open();
            queryString = "DELETE FROM wgcdoccab WHERE numdoc = (SELECT MAX(numdoc) FROM WGCDOCCAB WHERE serie ='1' and tipodoc ='FSS' and contribuinte ='999999990' and  datadoc = CONVERT(varchar(10),dateadd(dd, -1, getdate()),120))";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
        using (SqlConnection deleteconnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            deleteconnection.Open();

            queryString = "SELECT max(numdoc) FROM wgcdoccab WHERE serie ='1' and tipodoc ='FSS' and contribuinte ='999999990' and datadoc = CONVERT(varchar(10),(dateadd(dd, -1, getdate())), 120))";
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    check = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    check = false;
                    MessageBox.Show("Dados Apagados com sucesso");
                }
                command.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    while (check);
```

The code is relative simple, and after the end of the do - while, it becomes and endless cicle because it will always return a NULL value for the numdoc, i cant seem to find a way to go around it.
Any suggestions?

Comment: MAX() will always return a null instead of empty rows. Why not check for a null instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not understand the necessisty of a loop. Why don't you just delete all the records at once?

```
DELETE FROM wgcdoccab
WHERE 
    serie ='1' and
    tipodoc ='FSS' and
    contribuinte ='999999990' and
    datadoc = CONVERT(varchar(10),dateadd(dd, -1, getdate()),120))";
```

If you repeat your query in a loop it will delete all of these records anyway, not just the last ones.

And what does "the last ones" mean exactly? The last 2 ones the last 100 ones? You must give an exact definition of "last ones"!

Lets say that you want to delete the last 10 ones. You can achive it with this query (assuming T-SQL):

```
DELETE FROM wgcdoccab
WHERE numdoc IN (
    SELECT TOP 10 numdoc
    FROM WGCDOCCAB
    WHERE blahh blahh blahh
    ODER BY numdoc DESC
)
```

Comment: I dont want to delete all of the rows, just the ones that fit in to the clause, for example "Where numdoc(max) and etc" therefore i need to check 1 by one from the bottom until that is false on the table, sorry if i dont explain very well.

Comment: If you repeatedly delete the rows that match your where condition until no one of them remains, then it makes no difference whether you delete the one with MAX(numdoc) first or not. Every one of them in turn will have `numdoc = MAX(numdoc)` in your loop, beacuse `MAX(numdoc)` will be another one every time.

Comment: But i only want to delete the last ones of the previous day where the condition is true, not all of them, while condition is true delete, if not stop deleting and leave the rest.

Comment: Every one in turn will be the last one where the condition is true, because after you delete the last one, another one will be the last one. My first query deletes only the ones of the previous day where the condition is true. The thing with `MAX(numdoc)` makes no difference.

Comment: I understand now! one other question, if i select the last top 100, but there are only 99 last entries will it download the 99 or crash?

Comment: It will only select 99. No crash. The TOP clause only defines a maximum limit.